# get value from combo box to php

Tags: php, ajax, combobox

this is my combo box page coding:

```
<?php
echo "<form method=post align=center>
<div id=myDiv>
<select name=userselect>
<option value=empty></option>
<option value=Confirm> Confirm </option>
<option value=Processing> Processing </option>
<option value=Pending> Pending </option>
<option value=Cancelled> Cancelled </option>
</select>
<button type=button name=combobox value=combobox onclick=loadXMLDoc()>Update</button>
</div>
</form>";
?>
```

this is my php code (another page):

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['combobox']))
{
    $userselect = $_POST['userselect'];
    echo $userselect;
}
?>
```

if user select one value in combo box that value should store in db and then display what they are selected. for example if user select CONFIRM option that value stored in db after that it display CONFIRM instead of that combo box form and button. Here i can stored the combo box values in db successfully. thats not a problem and then here i used ajax method to show the msg instead of button place. Now, i want what user select it should display the same value. check these above coding and reply me ur suggestions...

Comment: please show me your ajax part..

Comment: function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","sample.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

Comment: in your success part you just append data in div not bind or select value in drop down. so please set value in drop down.

Comment: i set the values in select option but it didn't show what i'm selected

Comment: please show me code for that

Comment: <select name=userselect value=userselect>, in php if (isset($_POST['combobox']))
{
 $userselect = $_POST['userselect'];
 echo $userselect;
} is this correct?

Comment: you don't need to check in php it checked in ajax on success...

Comment: but i want to display the msg what i'm selected in combo box..

Comment: but you said it is also saved in db

Comment: subhash ... this is separate coding... now i'm trying separately. now i just want to display the msg what i'm selected in combo box. i already stored the values in db. i didn't write that db code here. thats not a problem man..

Comment: then you should use js for alert the selected value of combobox..

Comment: if i select that combo box values it should show in that place instead of combox box form and button. again we can't able to edit that combo box. understand now? this is not like a alert message man...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i got it what i want. without using ajax method i can store the data to db and then combobox, button hide permanently if once we updated the status. this is my final coding...

```
 if ( $a_row['status'] != 'empty' ) {
        echo "\t<td>" . $a_row[$status] . "</td>\n";
    } 
    else {
        echo "\t<td><form action=statusdb.php method=post>
        <select name=update>
        <option value=empty></option>
        <option value=Confirm>Confirm</option>
        <option value=Processing>Processing</option>
        <option value=Pending>Pending</option>
        <option value=Cancelled>Cancelled</option></select>
        <input name=id type=hidden value='".$a_row['slno']."';>
        <input type=submit value=Update>
       </form>
        </td>\n";
    }
```

statusdb coding:

```
if (isset($_POST['id']))
{ 
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
$update= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['update']);
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE guest_details SET status = '$update' WHERE slno = '$id'");
if(!$sql)
{
    die("Error" .mysql_error());
}
}
```

i posted another question ([php combobox & button should hide once updated into mysql db and show success message instead of combobox & button place.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19218788/php-combobox-button-should-hide-once-updated-into-mysql-db-and-show-success-me)). i got help from that answer... so, only i posted the correct answer here..

Answer (score 0):

Replace Your code with this:

```
<?php

//Connect To your Database File..

//After Connecting To Databse
$combo = mysqli_real_escape_string('yourconnectionlink', $_POST['userselect'])

echo "<form method='post' action='youractionfile.php' align='center'>
<div id='myDiv'>
<select name='userselect'>
<option value='empty'></option>
<option value='Confirm'> Confirm </option>
<option value='Processing'> Processing </option>
<option value='Pending'> Pending </option>
<option value='Cancelled'> Cancelled </option>
</select>
<input type='button' name='combobox' value='combobox'>Update</button>
</div>
</form>";

//Insert Data into Database File

if($_POST['userselect'])) {
   if(isset($_POST['userselect'])) {
     $query = "INSERT INTO tablename (your field names) VALUES ('".$combo."')";
     $res = mysqli_query('yourconnectionlink', $query);
     echo '1 row inserted';
   }
}
?>
```

Comment: i already stored the combo box value into database. now i want to display the msg what i am selected in combo box... for example if i'm select pending option it should show pending msg instead of that place(combo box form and button). stored the values in db thats a not a pbm now...

Comment: First query the table to select that value and then use while loop to show that value..

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc(yourqueryresult)) {
  $userSelect = $row['yourfieldnamefromtable'];
}

Not tested, but i think it should help you..