# php combobox & button should hide once updated into mysql db and show success message instead of combobox & button place.

Tags: php, button, combobox, hide

here i updated one field value through user input form (combo box type). update process is working perfectly. but, after data stored in db it should show the value what i'm selected in combo box and then that combox box & update button must hide once updated and it should show message "updated successfully" instead of combo box & button. NOT USING JAVASCRIPT ALERT METHOD. THIS IS NOT A ALERT MESSAGE. once updated data in db that combo box should hide and then success message should show in that particular .

this is my main page coding :

```
while($a_row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    { 
            echo "\t<td>" . $a_row['guestname'] . "</td>";
            echo "\t<td>" . $a_row['agentname'] . "</td>\n";
        echo "\t<td><form action=statusdb.php method=post>
        <select name=update><option value=empty></option><option value=Confirm>Confirm</option><option value=Processing>Processing</option><option value=Pending>Pending</option><option value=Cancelled>Cancelled</option></select>
        <input name=id type=hidden value='".$a_row['slno']."';>
        <input type=submit value=Update>
       </form>
        </td>\n";
        echo "</tr>\n";
    }
```

this is my statusdb coding :

```
if (isset($_POST['id']))
{ 
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
$update= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['update']);
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE guest_details SET status = '$update' WHERE slno = '$id'");
if(!$sql)
{
    die("Error" .mysql_error());
}
else
{
    echo "<html><body onload=\"alert('Status Updated Successfully');\"></body></html>";
}
}
```

Comment: use Ajax It's not just belongs to php and also Javascript and Ajax

Comment: ok i will use ajax method to hide and show another msg. but if i reload that page it will show the same combo box & button once again. i want to permanentely hide combobox & button once user updated data into db. if they reload that page it should show what user already updated? and what field they not yet to filled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking this would work.

Try adding the following after the line echoing the agentname:

```
if ( $a_row['status'] != 'empty' ) {
    echo "\t<td>" . $a_row[$status] . "</td>\n";
} else {
    // here's where you'd put the next 6 lines
}
```

PS: I don't see an opening `<tr>` tag.